# keyof returning different types with index signature

Tags: typescript, keyof

I have some confusion about how `keyof` works when I have an interface with an index signature.

As an example, if I have an interface as follows:

```
interface InterfaceOne {
  [id: string]: InterfaceOne[keyof InterfaceOne];
  a: SomeTypeOne;
  b: SomeTypeTwo;
}
```

I want a function that has a parameter that can only be a valid property of `InterfaceOne`, e.g.:

```
function test = (param: keyof InterfaceOne) => any
```

In the above function, I should be able to call `test('a')` or `test('b')`, however `test('c')` should result in a compile error since `c` is not a property in `InterfaceOne`.

This does not seem to work when I have the index signature in `InterfaceOne`.

`type myType = keyof InterfaceOne` returns `string | number`. If I remove the index signature it returns `"a" | "b"` as I expected.

Can someone please explain why adding an index signature changes the type returned by `keyof`? Also, what is the correct way that I can enforce that the parameter is a property name of `InterfaceOne`?

Comment: `c` *is* a property in `InterfaceOne`; by adding the index signature, you've said that *any* string will be a property name (with the value of type `SomeTypeOne | SomeTypeTwo`). If that's not the behaviour you want: why are you adding the index signature? Why *wouldn't* it change the result?

Comment: ah ok. I added the index signature because elsewhere in my app I need to access a property in `InterfaceOne` using a string like `obj[param] = ...` where `obj` is of type `InterfaceOne` and param would be `a` or `b` in the above example. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @sam but you can access a property using `obj[param]` even without index signature, provided that `param` is typed as `'a' | 'b'`, or course

Comment: If you want `param` to be one of the explicit property names and *don't* want other arbitrary properties to be accessible, then adding the index signature is exactly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I get it now. I got confused because I hadn't properly typed my `param` in my function so it was giving a compile error complaining that there was no index signature on my object type. Adding the correct type to the function parameter and removing the index signature has solved the issue. Thanks again!